# Git: does git push to all remote repositories?

Tags: git

I have a local git repository that I use in combination with a (private) remote git repo. The code I'm working on comes originally from an open-source project on github, so I added it as a remote to the github repository (with git remote add).

I noticed (with git remote -v) that for both, fetch and push, the remote repository has been added. According to another question here on SO, it's not possible to only have a fetch remote repo.  However, I only want to fetch from github, not push.

So, my question is: **the moment I do a git push, does it push to all the remote repositories (including the one from github, in this case), or only to my first remote repository?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git push MYREMOTE MYBRANCH
```

Will get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. (And you could easily just have tried that)

Comment: I tried actually, and I got no error, but still was unsure. Sorry! (and the description on the man-page was not definite to me, to be honest)

Answer (score -2):

git push origin will push all changes on the local repositories that have matching remote repositories at origin As for git push

Works like git push , where  is the current repositories's remote (or origin, if no remote is configured for the current branch).